# Schengen Visa Cancellation

Tags: visas, schengen

I Have a Schengen Visa issued by the Embassy of Norway valid from July 2018 to July 2019.
I applied and received another Visa from July 2019 ( the 2nd day of previous Visa expiry date) until July 2020.

in a telephone conversation with the employee in the embassy , I was told (verbally) that the previous Visa is cancelled.

However I have noticed that:

1. No cancellation stamp was put on the Visa itself
2. No document was attached to the passport stating that the
   previous valid visa is cancelled.

Especially that I had a similar case in the past and the same embassy (in another Country) and there was no cancellation of the previous visa and no interruption of my stay in the Schengen Area when the 1st expired and the following visa started!!

My Question is: How can I get an accurate information about the visa status in order to avoid any complication with the Customs in any EU country within June.

Comment: The most accurate information will come from the authorities themselves, not random guys on the internet. You simply have to take what you’ve been told at face value, unfortunately.

Comment: Is your new visa also from Norway?